# what is interface method in salesforce ? How Many types Of Interfaces Is ther In salesforce

Tags: interface

what is interface? when using interface? 
In Salesforce Give Me Explination

Comment: Also see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_interfaces.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard Salesforce Interface for Batch Apex. SFDC do have standard interfaces like Database.Batchable, Schedulable, etc.

For example, if you implement the Database.Batchable Interface, then you must implement the three methods defined in the Interface: Start, Execute and Finish

**Code:-**

**Interface:-
==========**

```
public interface PurchaseOrder {    
Double getDiscount();
 }
```

**ApexClass:-
===========**

```
public class Sample implements PurchaseOrder {        
Double discount;  
public void setDiscount(Double disc) {        
discount = disc;      
 }  

public Double getDiscount() {                
return 1.22;        
}
}
```

Comment: Now I  understood  About Interface In Batch Apex  interface